# How to handle floating-point numbers in Ethereum smart contracts?

Tags: ethereum, smartcontracts

recently, I’ve been learning about the development of Ethereum smart contracts. I have a question about the following code; the result obtained by the “a” method is 4. This result is the same as my common sense understanding because, in the floating-point processing, the corresponding floating-point number will be intercepted when running. However, when I call the method “b”, the result is 5. I don't understand this result very well. Is it because the compiler has optimised during the compilation process to calculate the outcome directly and store it? Thanks a lot, guys.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
 
contract Test {
    uint constant c = 5;
    
    function a() public pure returns(uint){
        return c/2 + c/2;
    }   
    
    function b() public pure returns(uint){
        return 5/2 + 5/2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that compiler optimize the `return 5/2 + 5/2;` line. In assembly output, after compiling with `solc-v0.8.13 --asm --optimize-run=100000`, there are following lines:

```
        /* "Test.sol":215:224  5/2 + 5/2 */
      0x05
        /* "Test.sol":208:224  return 5/2 + 5/2 */
      swap1
      pop
```

What indicates that `0x05` value is directly returned from function call.

In function `a` the integer division is [rounded down](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.13/types.html#division), so returned value is `0x04`. Compiler doesn't optimize this line, even though it operates on `constant` and literals, and allows to run integer division on EVM.

Worth mentioning is fact, that solidity is a language under continous development. So it's possible, that future compiler version will optimize code in such a way that functions in this example will give both the same results.